# WCF issue - wsHttpBinding with Username Authentication and TransportWithMessageCredentials

Tags: .net, wcf

I created a wcf services, hosted it in IIS(7.5) which works fine. I now want to add username authentication and i run into some problems.
The config file is this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="warServBehavior" name="WcfServiceLibrary.WarcraftService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IWarcraftService" bindingConfiguration="warWsHttpBinding" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="warWsHttpBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="warServBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="BogusValidator, App_Code"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Regarding the certificate i did the following(inspired from msdn):

1. 1)makecert -n "CN=RootCATest" -r -sv RootCATest.pvk RootCATest.cer
2. 2)added it to Trusted Root Certification Authorities
3. 3)makecert -sk CertTest -iv RootCATest.pvk -n "CN=Bogus" -ic RootCATest.cer -sr
       localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe

In IIS i added binding for https and in the Server Certificates i have this:
[image]

When i run svcutil https://localhost/WarcraftServiceSite/WarService.svc i get this exception: `"There was an error downloading https://localhost/WarcraftServiceSite/WarService.svc. The underlying connection was closed.Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."`

Later edit: it seems that the right way to call svcutil is with http not https even though i have this `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is just a test certificate you can add the following to the client for it to work. When you get a production certificate from verisign etc you won't need this.
Reference and add usings for the following - System.Net, System.Net.Security, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

Use the ServicePointManager class and add a handler to the ServerCertificateValidationCallback

```
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
               += RemoteCertificateValidate;
```

Then the handler impl

```
private static bool RemoteCertificateValidate(
   object sender, X509Certificate cert, 
    X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
{
    // trust any certificate
    return true;
}
```

Wire up the handler somewhere before using your proxy.
Remeber this code and certs from makecert should be used for testing only.